# Pooling already extracted dna?

Tags: dna

I had ethanol precipitated a large amount of DNA (2ml) and had to split the sample in half to spin down because only the microcentrifuge has the correct rotor to spin that fast. I want to get as concentrated of a DNA sample as possible. Is it possible (correct) to combine the resuspended DNA? I wanted a total of 30 ul of extracted DNA. Could I resuspend each of the two sample in 15 ul and then combine them?

What is the best way to go about this. I realize just keeping them separate might be the best option. I also realized I could've lost DNA when transferring the sample to a smaller tube. I did this because I don't believe it is correct to spin for longer at a lower speed...

Comment: Assuming you are using standard 1.5ml microcentrifuge tubes, it is completely possible to resuspend a dried DNA pellet from an ethanol/isopropanol precipitation. I have resuspended RNA pellets in 10µl water frequently with no issues.

Comment: But then can I combine the resuspensions?

Comment: I see no reason it will cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me...

- You can resuspend the two separate pellets (A and B) in 10ul each.
- Collate in one tube (add A to B).
- Use the remaining 10ul  from your desired volume to 'wash out' tube B and add the wash to tube A.

So long as the DNA is from the same sample this is a perfectly reasonable step that should not result in a substantial loss.